# Mapping of images to get particular data image on hover

Tags: reactjs

Code below is an example of creation by me in code sandbox. I map sum of images and try to hover image and get that image details...if I hover on one image its getting all images data.

Can anyone help on this: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-haslett-qreg1?file=/src/App.js:0-1096

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class Images extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Images: [
        { text: "sun", image: require("./images/sun.webp") },
        { text: "sky", image: require("./images/sky.jpg") },
        { text: "tree", image: require("./images/tree.jpg") }
      ],
      hover: false
    };
  }
  Hover = () => {
    this.setState({
      hover: true
    });
  };
  NotHover = () => {
    this.setState({
      hover: false
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="icon">
        {this.state.Images.map((image, key) => (
          <div>
            <img
              className="image"
              onMouseEnter={this.Hover}
              onMouseLeave={this.NotHover}
              src={image.image}
              alt=""
            />
            {this.state.hover && 
            <div>
              <li>{image.text}</li>
              
              </div>}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save a state for hover status of each image by its key

```js
export default class Images extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Images: [
        { text: "sun", image: require("./images/sun.webp") },
        { text: "sky", image: require("./images/sky.jpg") },
        { text: "tree", image: require("./images/tree.jpg") }
      ],
      hover: {
        0: false,
        1: false,
        2: false
      }
    };
  }
  AddressMenuBox = (key) => () => {
    this.setState({
      hover: { [key]: true }
    });
  };
  AddressMenuBoxLeave = (key) => () => {
    this.setState({
      hover: { [key]: false }
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="icon">
        {this.state.Images.map((image, key) => (
          <div>
            <img
              className="image"
              onMouseEnter={this.AddressMenuBox(key)}
              onMouseLeave={this.AddressMenuBoxLeave(key)}
              src={image.image}
              alt=""
            />
            {this.state.hover[key] && (
              <div>
                <li>{image.text}</li>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Codesandbox for implementation

[image: Edit jolly-mclaren-ofobl]

Comment: thanks very much for your solution....its solved very fast

Answer (score 0):

You have to differentiate between the elements to force hover only on selected image, therefore you could provide additional `id` property to your images and change `hover` state to `hoverTargetId` so that it represents an id of selected item.

```
export  default  class  Images  extends  Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state  = {
            Images: [
                { id:  0, text:  "sun", image:  require("./images/sun.webp") },
                { id:  1, text:  "sky", image:  require("./images/sky.jpg") },
                { id:  2, text:  "tree", image:  require("./images/tree.jpg") }
            ],
            hoverTargetId:  null
        };
    }
    onHoverStart  = targetId => () => {
        this.setState({ hover:  targetId });
    };

    onHoverEnd  = () => { 
        this.setState({ hover:  null });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div  className="icon">
                {this.state.Images.map((image, key) => (
                    <div  key={key}>
                        <img
                            className="image"
                            onMouseEnter={this.onHoverStart(image.id)}
                            onMouseLeave={this.onHoverEnd}
                            src={image.image}
                            alt=""
                        />
                        {this.state.hover === image.id &&
                            <div>
                                <li>{image.text}</li>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The `id` i've introduced could be substituted by your iteration index (`key`), but it's a better practice to not handle such things based on dynamically generated values.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with the boolean variable to show target image:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class Images extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Images: [
        { text: "sun", image: require("./images/sun.webp"), show: false },
        { text: "sky", image: require("./images/sky.jpg"), show: false },
        { text: "tree", image: require("./images/tree.jpg"), show: false }
      ],
      hover: false
    };
  }
  AddressMenuBox = (key) => {
    let items = [...this.state.Images];
    let item = { ...items[key] };
    item.show = true;
    items[key] = item;
    this.setState({
      hover: true,
      Images: items
    });
  };
  AddressMenuBoxLeave = (key) => {
    let items = [...this.state.Images];
    let item = { ...items[key] };
    item.show = false;
    items[key] = item;
    this.setState({
      hover: false,
      Images: items
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="icon">
        {this.state.Images.map((image, key) => (
          <div>
            <img
              className="image"
              onMouseEnter={() => this.AddressMenuBox(key)}
              onMouseLeave={() => this.AddressMenuBoxLeave(key)}
              src={image.image}
              alt=""
            />
            {this.state.hover && image.show && (
              <div>
                <li>{image.text}</li>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit code on sanbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-gagarin-54zv4?file=/src/App.js:0-1462